# How to change widget data source dynamically, with click action on another widget

Tags: dynamic, widget, dashboard, thingsboard

I have a line chart and 3 simple card widgets on the same page/state of a dashboard.
Each card shows a different telemetry reading  (but all readings are from the same asset, they are not different devices because they all come from the same box with multiple sensors).
I would like the chart to change the data source depending on the card I click on (like when you navigate to a different state)
I know that actions/states work with entities, but I don't know if they work with readings.
Also, I would like to have all this on the same page, instead of navigating to a different page, that is what usually happens when you navigate to a different state.
Is this possible?

Comment: Would using the charts Legend and hiding certain keys work? Load the widget with all datasources, and then just choose what to display?

Comment: Hi JB, that's an interesting approach. And if you do it manually by clicking on the legend it works. What I'm trying to achieve is to filter what is shown depending on a click on another widget. For example, I'm measuring Light, Sound, and Humidity, and I have one card with the current value for each measure. When I click on the Sound card, I'd like the chart to show only Sound values and the same with the other measures. How would you trigger the hide/show of the keys in the chart from the action of the other widget? (the one that you click on).